# How to read a file on a remote server from openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-3

I have an app (java, Spring boot) that runs in a container in openshift. The application needs to go to a third-party server to read the logs of another application. How can this be done? Can I mount the directory where the logs are stored to the container? Or do I need to use some Protocol to remotely access the file and read it?

A remote server is a normal Linux server. It runs an old application running as a jar. It writes logs to a local folder. An application that runs on a pod (with Linux) needs to read this file and parse it

Answer (score 2):

There is a multiple way to do this.
If a continious access is needed :

- A **Watcher** access with polling events ( WatchService API )
- A **Stream Buffer**
- File **Observable** with Java rx

Then creating an **NFS** storage could be a possible way with exposing the remote logs and make it as a **persistant volume** is better for this approach.

Else, if the access is based on pollling the logs at for example a certain time during the day then a solution consist of using an **FTP** solution like **Apache Commons FTP Client**  or using an ssh client which have an **SFTP** implementation like  [JSch](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-sftp) which is a native Java library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494378/how-to-connect-from-spring-boot-application-to-nfs-server-directory-to-save-file. this is a related question. Please could you help